# How to link custom fonts when 'react-native link' isn't working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to link a custom font in a react-native project.

I have other libraries preventing me from running `react-native link`.

I have run:

`react-native link ./src/assets/fonts/`

`react-native link src/assets/fonts/`

`react-native link ./src/assets/fonts`

`react-native link src/assets/fonts`

`react-native link assets`

All of these yield "Error: Failed to get dependency config"

here is my package.json:
[image]

here is my directory structure:

[image]

Have I missed something? How can I get these fonts linked natively?

Comment: please provide me your react-native version?

Comment: React-Native version is 0.59.5

Comment: please redo `react-native link` on cmd, not bash or power shell.

Comment: I don't know what cmd is, I'm on a Mac. Why would shell matter

Answer (score 0):

In react native iOS, you can directly include them from XCode, by adding the font files to your project, and them including them in the `Copy Bundle Resources` section in `Build Phases`.

Then they are available to you in react native ios code